# Jackson serializing according to interface

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have Jackson JSON as serializer for my REST API. For Order entity I have getAll and getById methods. For getById API returns whole Order object with all properties, but for getAll method I wish to return only some properties defined in OrderForList interface (Order implements OrderForList).

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Set<OrderForList> getAll() {
    Set<OrderForList> orders = orderService.get(); //get() returns Set<Order>
    return orders;
}
```

How can I do that?

I already tryied to annotate method with

```
@JsonSerialize(typing = JsonSerialize.Typing.STATIC, contentAs = OrderForList.class)
```

without any effect. I can write custom serializer/mapper but I am looking for some better solution. I am using this solution on property objects (e.q. Order's supplier, where I am returning only supplier's id and name) and it works, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the [view annotation](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) ? It might help you

Comment: Thank you for that idea, I will try it.